# structured streaming fetched wrong current offset from kafka

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

when running spark structured streaming using lib: `"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql-kafka-0-10" % "2.4.0"`, we keep getting error regarding current offset fetching:

> Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage
>   failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost
>   task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, qa2-hdp-4.acuityads.org, executor 2):
>   java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: latest offs et
>   -9223372036854775808 does not equal -1 at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:170) at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaMicroBatchInputPartitionReader.resolveRange(KafkaMicroBatchReader.scala:371)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaMicroBatchInputPartitionReader.(KafkaMicroBatchReader.scala:329)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaMicroBatchInputPartition.createPartitionReader(KafkaMicroBatchReader.scala:314)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceRDD.compute(DataSourceRDD.scala:42)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324) at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288) at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324) at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288) at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324) at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288) at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324) at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288) at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121) at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
>   at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

for some reason, looks like fetchLatestOffset returned a Long.MIN_VALUE for one of the partitions. I checked the structured streaming checkpoint, that was correct, it's the currentAvailableOffset was set to Long.MIN_VALUE.

kafka broker version: 1.1.0.
lib we used:

```
{{libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql-kafka-0-10" % "2.4.0" }}
```

how to reproduce:
basically we started a structured streamer and subscribed a topic of 4 partitions. then produced some messages into topic, job crashed and logged the stacktrace like above.

also the committed offsets seem fine as we see in the logs:

```
=== Streaming Query ===
Identifier: [id = c46c67ee-3514-4788-8370-a696837b21b1, runId = 31878627-d473-4ee8-955d-d4d3f3f45eb9]
Current Committed Offsets: {KafkaV2[Subscribe[REVENUEEVENT]]: {"REVENUEEVENT":{"0":1}}}
Current Available Offsets: {KafkaV2[Subscribe[REVENUEEVENT]]: {"REVENUEEVENT":{"0":-9223372036854775808}}}
```

so spark streaming recorded the correct value for partition: 0, but the current available offsets returned from kafka is showing Long.MIN_VALUE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the issue, this is due to a integer overflow inside the spark structured streaming library. details are posted here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-26718

Comment: it's resolved. fix will be out for spark 2.3.2, 2.4.1 and 3.0.0.